# Applet is empty with absolute layout

Tags: java, browser, netbeans, applet

I want to create a hangman game as an applet, so I have some labels and buttons that will be initialized by the generated code of the gui designer but I also have some labels I create on my own, after knowing how long my word is. Therefore I use absolute layout for my applet.

In netbeans my applet works finde when I run it but when I try to run it in the browser (I tried Firefox and IE) nothing is on the display, the applet is empty.

can someone help me with that?

Here you can find the source if it is helpful
http://root.xelluloid.de/Hedgeman/Hedgeman.java

With kind regards

Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at the Java console for the browser?  It likely contains something that says that the program crashed because it could not find the AbsoluteLayout class.

This is for an older version of NetBeans, but the same should apply: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=597783

Comment: This link appears to be dead

Comment: I'd delete the answer... but it is accepted... and hopefully has enough info for someone to find more info. I'll see if I can find an updated source...

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same trouble with an applet and `AbsoluteLayout` and netbeans 7.1.

Everything works fine but errors are thrown when the applet runs from a browser.

I solved this by switching, in the form designer, from `AbsoluteLayout` to "Free Design" (which seems to default to `GroupLayout` in the code that is actually generated) but offers similar functionality (widgets can be placed without restrictions, borders, or even on top of others).

You could probably include the AbsoluteLayout Class/jar into your project and continue using this code. But in my case the code can't exceed 32KB and needs to be self contained (single file) as it needs to be uploaded to a small [embedded device](http://www.newark.com/advantech/adam-6060-be/i-o-module/dp/53M6172).